# Cordova navigator.device issue

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am using phonegap to build android application using JavaScript and HTML. I am trying to include audio and video features in my application. It is giving error capture of undefined for following code. Can anybody suggest me better way to handle audio and video feature?

```
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of phonegap/cordova are you using for development?
You need to manually add the plugin for phonegap/cordova 3.+ onward.
Camera plugin link [here](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.camera)
To manually add plugin.

To add the camera plugin use the below command

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-camera.git
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for help. Actually, i am using cordova 3.3 and I have already added the plugin you have mentioned. I also have added audio and video plugins. But still it is giving me error. Do i need to use anything other than navigator.device.capture? It shows navigator.device as undefined in phone.

Comment: are you checking for **deviceready** event before calling the device.capture function call.

Comment: Worked now. Some plugin was not installed properly i guess. Thanks a lot for help. I have one more doubt regarding storage. How can I store these videos and audio files inside my project folder? Currently It is storing in  gallery.

Comment: look at the file API plugins documentation they should probably help you out. I am not too familiar with the file APIs.